# C# Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to develop a desktop application (winforms) that uses a website database. I am currently working on local database to avoid wasting host traffic while developing.

I've encountered a scenario where I've spent 2 days googling and cannot find a concrete answer on how to achieve a special kind of array.

Currently I am trying to retrieve users information from database as an array, but I need a few items to also be an array, while others remain as string.

In PHP I use something like:

```
$user["username"] = $result["username"];
$user["name"] = $result["name"];
$user["lastname"] = $result["lastname"];
```

And so on. The problem comes with the query that retrieve phone number from database, since most users have at least 2 numbers (home and cell)

```
foreach ($phones as $type => $phone) {
  $user["phone"][$type] = $phone;
}
```

Where $type is the kind of phone (home line, main cell, work cell, pager, etc) and $phone contains the number.
So, as far as I've searched, and everything I've read, I've learned this

`Dictionary<string, string>` can make an array using the first string as the array key, and the second the array value, but second string can't be converted to array
`Dictionary<string, List<string>>` can make a second level array, but can't store a string as a value. (`Can't convert 'string' into 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`)

So, what could be the best way to achieve this particular scenario? How can I make an array hold both string and array data?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use PHP as an example of retrieving data from a database in C#. I would read the data into a custom class that supports the format required. Something like `$user["phone"][$type]` is basically a nested `Dictionary`, which is not something I ever want to see in code.

Comment: You are probably looking for an array of arrays, also called a 'jagged array'. That could fit whatever custom object you want. This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Comment: The `foreach` line explicitly shows I am using key value inside an already assigned key from `$user`. Sorry for not knowing the C# parlance, but if you read carefully, the `key => value` format is very explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of apporaching this task is an array of structs

```
public struct DatabaseNode
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Name;
        public string Lastname;
        public Dictionary<string,string> Phones;

        public DatabaseNode(string user,string name,string lastname,string housephone)
        {
            Username = user;
            Name = name;
            Lastname = lastname;
            Phones = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Phones.Add("House", housephone);
        }

        public void Add_Phone(string type,string num)
        {
            Phones.Add(type, num);
        }
    }
```

Using this one could easily have an Array of DatabaseNodes and store different data even convert data before use if necessary.

Comment: That sounds promising. Should I create that structure in another file on the project? Which will be the best approach for implementing it?

Comment: You can put it in a seprate file. for me i keep structs small and with the class that uses it. 
to use this you want to do
DatabaseNode[] Nodes=new DatabaseNode[20]; (or a list if you prefer)
then populate it
Nodes[0]=new  DatabaseNode("FluffBall","Joe","Blogs","0000000000000");
if you need more phones use 
Nodes[0].Add_Phone("Work","1111111111111111");

Comment: No need to do an array of that. I already have an array of the users with only username, this extra info is gonna be displayed when an administrator or moderator double click on a user from a table, so no need to do an array of users, just array of user data.